# Sum of two Count in one query

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Files and folders can be "inside" folders. I need to get the count of files and folders in each folder in queryset.

models.py

```
class Folder(models.Model):
    id = ShortUUIDField(primary_key=True, default=ShortUUIDField.random, editable=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    parent = models.ForeignKey("self", null=True, blank=True, related_name="children", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    description = models.JSONField()

class File(models.Model):
    id = ShortUUIDField(primary_key=True, default=ShortUUIDField.random, editable=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    folder = models.ForeignKey(Folder, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    description = models.JSONField(default=default_file_description)
    show_in_catalog = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

serializers.py

```
class FolderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    title = serializers.CharField(source='description.title')
    element_count = serializers.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = Folder
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'element_count']
```

I tried to count it like that:

views.py

```
    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        folder = self.get_object()
        
        return Response(
            dict(
                parent=folder.parent_id,
                folders=FolderSerializer(
                    Folder.objects.filter(
                        parent=folder,
                        user__user__username=CONTENT_USER
                    ).alias(
                        file_count=Count("file", filter=Q(file__show_in_catalog=True))
                    ).alias(
                        folder_count=Count("children")
                    ).annotate(
                        element_count=F('file_count') + F('folder_count') # This count i need
                    ),
                    many=True,
                ).data
            )
        )
```

But it works incorrect :(

**I need to count it in views.py not in serializer, using SerializerMethodField and smth like that.**

**UPD:**

**SOLVED** You must add distinct=True in both Count

views.py

```
    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        folder = self.get_object()
        
        Folder.objects.filter(
           parent=folder,
           user__user__username=CONTENT_USER
        ).annotate(
            element_count=Count(
                "file",
                filter=Q(file__show_in_catalog=True),
                distinct=True
            ) + Count(
                "children",
                distinct=True
            )
        )
        
        return Response(
            dict(
                parent=folder.parent_id,
                folders=FolderSerializer(
                    folders,
                    many=True,
                ).data
            )
        )
```